# Diagonalization of matrices over semirings

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras

I was wondering if anyone happens to know results for diagonalizing matrices over semirings. I was able to find a result for commutative rings:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869312005601

However, I have been having trouble finding results for semirings, as well as general rings.